# Sigma curve and curvedArrow edge type renders as a line

Tags: javascript, sigma.js

I am messing around with Sigma and I cannot seem to get the lines to curve. Regular arrows work ok, but curved do not.

```js
var graphData = {
  "nodes": [
    { "id": "n0", "label": "A node", "x": 0, "y": 0, "size": 3 },
    { "id": "n1", "label": "Another node", "x": 3, "y": 1, "size": 2 },
    { "id": "n2", "label": "And a last one", "x": 1, "y": 3, "size": 1 },

    { "id": "n3", "label": "A node", "x": 2, "y": 0, "size": 8, "color": "#48ec51" },
    { "id": "n4", "label": "Another node", "x": 0, "y": 2, "size": 5, "color": "#5148ec" },
    { "id": "n5", "label": "And a last one", "x": 2, "y": 3, "size": 3, "color": "#ec48ec" }
  ],
  "edges": [
    { "id": "e0", "source": "n0", "target": "n1", "type": "curvedArrow", "size": 5 },
    { "id": "e1", "source": "n1", "target": "n2", "type": "curvedArrow" },
    { "id": "e2", "source": "n2", "target": "n0", "type": "curvedArrow" },

    { "id": "e3", "source": "n3", "target": "n4", "type": "arrow", "size": 3 },
    { "id": "e4", "source": "n4", "target": "n5", "type": "arrow", "size": 2 },
    { "id": "e5", "source": "n5", "target": "n3", "type": "arrow", "size": 1 }
  ]
};

// Initialize the Sigma graph
const sigmaInstance = new sigma({ 
  graph: graphData,
  container: 'sigma-container',
  settings: {
    defaultNodeColor: '#ec5148',
    defaultEdgeType: 'arrow',
    minEdgeSize: 5,
    maxEdgeSize: 5
  }
});

// Refresh the edges. Comment this out to see the arrows...
var types = [ 'line', 'curve', 'arrow', 'curvedArrow' ];
sigmaInstance.graph.edges().forEach(function(e) { e.type = types[3]; });
sigmaInstance.refresh();

// Set initial zoom
sigmaInstance.cameras[0].goTo({ x: 1, y: 1, angle: 0, ratio: 2.0 });

// Add drag listener
let dragListener = sigma.plugins.dragNodes(sigmaInstance, sigmaInstance.renderers[0]);
```

```css
body {
   background: #ddd;
 }
 h1 {
   text-align: center;
 }
 .sigma-wrapper {
   max-width: 300px;
   background: #fff;
   border: 2px solid #AAA;
   margin: auto;
 }
 #sigma-container {
   max-width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
 }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sigma.js/1.2.1/sigma.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sigma.js/1.2.1/plugins/sigma.parsers.json.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sigma.js/1.2.1/plugins/sigma.plugins.dragNodes.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sigma.js/1.2.1/plugins/sigma.renderers.parallelEdges.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/9c940aa9/src/renderers/canvas/sigma.canvas.edges.curve.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/9c940aa9/src/renderers/canvas/sigma.canvas.edges.arrow.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/9c940aa9/src/renderers/canvas/sigma.canvas.edges.curvedArrow.js"></script>
<h1>Sigma JS Workbench</h1>
<div class="sigma-wrapper">
  <div id="sigma-container"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

A [Github user](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/issues/848#issuecomment-367454376) solved this by specifying a canvas renderer.

```
const sigmaInstance = new sigma({ 
  graph: graphData,
  container: 'sigma-container',
  ...

  // canvas renderer
  // ===============
  renderer: {
    container: document.getElementById('sigma-container'),
    type: sigma.renderers.canvas
  }
});
```

Comment: I do have a canvas render but the curved arrows don't show except on hover, and a straight line is still rendered between nodes, any clue?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a late answer but I hope it still helps someone out there with this problem.

If you are using the minified library file sigma.min.js to include the sigma core library then the problem is most likely coming from there. If you open the gruntfile used to compile the minified file, the file names pointing to the curved edges files are wrong:

```
'src/renderers/canvas/sigma.canvas.edges.dotCurve.js',
'src/renderers/canvas/sigma.canvas.edges.arrow.js',
'src/renderers/canvas/sigma.canvas.edges.dotCurvedArrow.js'
```

they should be this ones (without the "dot"):

```
'src/renderers/canvas/sigma.canvas.edges.curve.js',
'src/renderers/canvas/sigma.canvas.edges.arrow.js',
'src/renderers/canvas/sigma.canvas.edges.curvedArrow.js'
```

Hope it helped!